# How can I order by Greek Letters and Normal Letters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a mix of greek and normal words and now the order of these is that the normal words comes first and then all the greek words. I want them to get mixed in the order so `beta` in greek is the same as `B`.

How can I make this `ORDER BY` in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

When ordering, you can specify the [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176557%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to use.

So, for greek you would use:

```
ORDER BY textField 
COLLATE 124
```

See [a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176552%28SQL.80%29.aspx) of collations (there are several greek ones), that can be used with [ORDER BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

Comment: Ok, I have several languages though. I have to set a new collate for each one of them... I will give it a try! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Greek there should be both an omicron and omega (if the alphabet didn't change too much the last 2000 years :-) ). Where do you want the latin O to end up?